# Given a list of string that contains 2 numbers find the path from the start to the end

Tags: java, string

I am trying to solve this question within quickest time for joining string together.

> You are given a list of N-1 strings of 2 numbers `"A B", Where A≠B and 1≤A,B≤N. Return an array that gives the order of Start till the end of the route.

Example

```
Input                     Output
3
"3 2"                     {3,2,4,1}
"4 1"
"3 4"

Input                      Output
2
"1 2"                      {1,2,3}
"1 3"
```

Initially, I have thought of just using Hashmap to solve this, but I realized there can be multiple keys with different value and I do not know how to proceed. Is there a faster method to solve this?

```
public class StringContUsingHashMap {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        Map<Integer, Integer> keyValue= new HashMap<Integer, Integer>(noOfStr);
        BufferedReader bR = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        int noOfStr = Integer.parseInt(bR.readLine());
        int[] store = new int[noOfStr];
        for (int j =0; j< noOfStr-2; j++){
            String[] keyValues = bR.readLine().split(" ");
            keyValue.put(Integer.parseInt(keyValues[0]),Integer.parseInt(keyValues[1]));
        }
        String[] keyValues = bR.readLine().split(" ");
        int first =Integer.parseInt(keyValues[0]);
        int last=Integer.parseInt(keyValues[1]);
        keyValue.put(first,last);
        int i =0;
        for (;first != last; first = keyValue.get(first)){
            store[i] =first;
            i++;
        }
        System.out.println(store.toString());
    }
}
```

Comment: I might be a bit obtuse, but I can't even figure out what is being asked here. What is the first number before the strings? What is the meaning of key and value in this context? Who is the key for what value? How is this joining strings together? What does a route mean in this context? Route from where to where? Sorry... ( ps. did not downvote, wasn't me )

Comment: The first number is the N number of strings given. There the key and value is what I tried to solve this question. After determining the order I planned to use String builder to join all of them together so that the String cont is O(1).

Comment: _You are given a list of N strings of 2 numbers `"A B", Where A≠B and 1≤A,B≤N_  But in the first example `B = 4` and `B > N = 3`.  Same in the second example: `N = 2 < B = 3`

Answer (score 0):

By the test data it seems that in the output the numbers should be collected into a set (without duplicates) keeping the order of insertion, that is, a `LinkedHashSet` could be used:

```java
static Set<Integer> process(String ... pairs) {
    return Arrays.stream(pairs)
                 .flatMap(p -> Arrays.stream(p.split("\\s+")))
                 .map(Integer::valueOf)
                 .collect(Collectors.toCollection(LinkedHashSet::new));
}
```

Tests

```java
System.out.println(process("3 2", "4 1", "3 4")); // [3, 2, 4, 1]
System.out.println(process("1 2", "1 3"));        // [1, 2, 3]
```